# Is this a mistake in Do Carmo's Riemannian geometry?

Tags: riemannian-geometry

Tell me if I'm wrong but the following expression from Do Carmo's Riemannian geometry (p.198) can't be correct right?

[image]

(here $[\partial_s, \partial_t] = 0$ and $f$ is a variation which you can think of as a map from two dimensional manifold with coordinates $s,t$ to the manifold of interest $M$).

It is used in calculating the second variation of the energy for curves on Riemannian manifolds. From what I know it should be
$$ R\left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial s}, \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} \right) \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} = \nabla_{\partial_s} \nabla_{\partial_t} \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} - \nabla_{\partial_t} \nabla_{\partial_s} \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} - \nabla_{[\partial_s, \partial_t]}\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$$
where the last term vanishes, giving us
$$ \nabla_{\partial_s} \nabla_{\partial_t} \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} = \nabla_{\partial_t} \nabla_{\partial_s} \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} + R\left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial s}, \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} \right) \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$$
where clearly the derivatives w.r.t $s$ and $t$ as arguments in the riemann tensor switched places in comparison to Do Carmo's expression.

The reason I put this on here is because I have seen this in other articles as well and I am wondering if I am making some dum mistake I don't see. Can anyone point out this mistake or verify this is indeed wrong in Do Carmo's book.

Comment: What definition of the Riemann curvature tensor is do Carmo using?  What definition is the other articles using?  Every author seems to use a different convention in my experience, and will lead to these kinds of troubles.

Comment: Well that seems to solve the problem! Indeed they use another definition. Didn't think there were different ways of defining the curvature tensor.

Comment: As an addition comment: Regardless of the convention, these situations rarely happen with the Ricci tensor due to the symmetries of the Riemannian curvature tensor (maybe just a sign change). Also, these symmetries are why there are so many different conventions and why they’re all (essentially) equivalent.